# Moving two letters at once (Sub Strings) Java

Tags: java

So I have my whole program working, it even moves on letter if it isn't a vowel, however it's suppose to move the two constant if they are right next to each other. So I have messed around with the substrings and making the char at (0) a variable, but still haven't got any luck any ideas?

So it would be the if (true) part.

Here is my code:

Comment: In case you cannot use regular expressions (as in the answer), I’d loop over the characters in the word, testing each letter to see if it’s a vowel, stopping at the first vowel encountered. I’d probably want to write me a static utility method `isVowel(char letter)` that I would call from within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex match look for the vowels and return the first occurrence. The code snippet below will look for the first vowel in the word and return the its index. Then you can use that in your substring instead of just taking the first letter.

```
String word = "test";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[aeiou]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word); 
if(matcher.find()){
  System.out.println(matcher.start());
}
```

Comment: Sweet, probably works. But dont know if I can use that as of rn.

Comment: If the user enters a word that does not contain any vowel? You should probably give an appropriate error message.

Comment: Is there no way to just change my code slightly to make it work?

Comment: If you're unable to use regex, then you'll have to do if checks for each vowel. You can use indexOf("a").. etc to check for the first occurrence of a specific letter. You'll want to check for all 5 vowels and take the smallest non-negative value returned.  -1 indicates that it isn't found in the word.